# How to use javascript get element to modify background color of div element?

Tags: javascript, css

Can't figure out how to modify the background color of the id someInput (which is a div).
Code :

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19) + 1;
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var color1 = document.getElementById("someInput");
if (number == 1) {
    img1.src = "golconda.jpeg";
    color1.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

I successfully changed the image source for the id img1 but cannot change the background color. It works in CSS but I need to be able to change it in JS.
Thanks for the help.

Tried other solutions online but didn't find anything.

Comment: It should be `color1.style.backgroundColor`

Comment: I changed it to that but it still doesn't work ☹️

Comment: Is it because `number` isn't `1`?

Comment: oh my god i have been trying to fix this for days. Thanks i am just a little dumb

Comment: The best way to change the background color of an element is to use Javascript to add or remove a class on that element, using a class name that describes the _state_ of a thing (or the _type_ of a thing) — for example `color1.classList.toggle('warning');` — and then apply the color in a stylesheet rule `.warning { background-color: red; }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How to use JavaScript to change div backgroundColor](/q/1874560/90527)", "[How do I change the background color with JavaScript?](/q/197748/90527)"

Answer (score 1):

`backgroundColor` is not a property of the html element `color1`. Html elements have a `style` property and `backgroundColor` is a property of `style`. Therefore your code should be like this:

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19) + 1;
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var color1 = document.getElementById("someInput");
if (number == 1) {
    img1.src = "golconda.jpeg";
    color1.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget to put style there and it should be only background instead backgroundcolor.

color1.style.background = 'red';

Comment: why it should only be `background` instead `backgroundColor`? have you try `backgroundColor`?

Comment: It shoudn't be necessarilly `background`, it can be `backgroundColor` and I would preffer to use it in this case, because is more specific. `background` is a shorthand for the following properties: `background-attachment`, `background-clip`, `background-image`, `background-origin`, `background-position`, `background-repeat`, `background-size`, and also `background-color`. They all could be defined together using only `background`.